# Jackson deserializing JSON into multiple POJOs

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

Hi I have following JSON

```
{
 "code": 0,
 "response": {
  "userObject": {
   "User": {
    "id": "355660",
    "first_name": "Dummy",
    "last_name": "dummy",
    "email": "dumb@email.com",
    "birthday": "2012-05-07",
    "created": "2012-08-21 06:41:05",
    "modified": "2012-08-21 06:41:05",
    "image_url": null,
   },
   "Location": {
    "id": "273550",
    "name": "New York City",
    "asciiName": "New York City",
    "lat": "40.714272",
    "lon": "-74.005966",
    "geoname_modified": "2011-11-08 00:00:00",
    "timeZone": "America/New_York",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "state": "New York",
    "created": "2012-07-12 12:11:01",
    "modified": "2012-08-20 14:27:24"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I have two classes, one each for  `Location`  and  `User`

I know that I can get the objects if I create nested class like

```
    response
     ->UserObject
         *User
         *Location
```

But i don't want to create two extra classes for  `UserObject`  and  `response` just for wrapping the two POJO's .
Is there any simpler way to do it??

I am using `Jackson Parser`  with `Spring for android`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it in two steps, if you really want to avoid throw-away classes, like:

```
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(...);
User user = mapper.treeToValue(tree.path("response").path("userObject").get("User"), User.class);
Location loc = mapper.convertValue(tree.path("response").path("userObject").get("Location"), Location.class);
```

but yeah I might go with silly struct-classes instead:

```
static class Response {
  public UserObject userObject;
}
static class UserObject {
  public Location Location;
  public User User;
}
```

since it really isn't much more code.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating `classes` you could create `arrays` or use `hashmap`. Personally, I would just create the `classes`. I think that this give you more flexibility in your app, and will allow you to work with the objects with less hassle. I know it takes time to set them up, but once you do that, you can use `ArrayList` and you can parse the `JSON` quite a bit easier.

Comment: yeah creating classes would simplify things a bit. but I was wondering if it could be done with `Jackson Tree Model` or `Jackson Data Bind` in not too complex way.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not familiar with either of those. When I parse `JSONObjects` I just put them into classes. I guess it all depends on what you are going to be doing with the data. If you plan on passing the data from `Activity` to `Activity`, you may want to use the classes. Also, keep in mind, any tree model is just a way the data is related.